# Input for unanticipated risk premium estimation

Tags: fixed-income, spread, risk-premium

In the paper "Economic Forces and the Stock Market" by Chen, Roll and Ross, unanticipated risk premium (URP) is tested as a potential risk factor for stock returns. This factor is commonly calculated as the difference between the return on a low-grade bond index and the return on a portfolio of long-term government bonds.

However, in this paper, there is no mention as to what *type* of return is used to compute URP. Any guess as to whether it would be Month-to-date total return, Yield to maturity, ...?

Comment: This is really too basic so I'm gonna close this. The answer is *it depends*, how you compute your risk-premium, which is actually often referred as *spread*. You can look at this [post](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3319/what-is-the-difference-between-option-adjusted-spread-oas-and-z-spread) where I discuss some of the spread measures.

Comment: The post is absolutely not related to my question. My question is also not basic at all, since there is a confusion as to the inputs of unanticipated risk premium (yield, vs. total return vs. price return). I am fully aware of what unanticipated risk premium is, but the computation differs in literature.

Comment: I misunderstand it then, I'll let the community answer it then. Feel free to add background to your questions to make sure if there is usual *confusion* in a topic as you say.